# MYSQL join two tables comparing with two columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables 
1)users(id,registerdate)
2)user_answer(userid,answer,updated_date)

I want the count of zero usage per day. How many users are registering but not answering per day. Results will be like this:

```
Date        registedCount   notAnsweredCount

15-09-02    20              10
15-09-01    20              10
15-08-31    12              4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the precise conditions by which you determine that a user "did not answer" in a particular day?

Comment: Can you please provide the scripts to create your tables and some sample data if possible?

Comment: Ollie Jones, "did not answer" means user has registered but not answered

Comment: dchar, Data will be like for user table((1,'15-09-01'),(2,'15-09-01'),(3,'15-09-01'))  for user answer table ((1,0,15-09-01))..  Here you can see three users are registered on the day of sep 01, 2015 but the only one user has answered one question. So, result will be (Date=>15-09-01,  registedCount => 3, notAnsweredCount => 2)

Answer (score 0):

Using a SUM of the result of an IF statement:-

```
SELECT date_range.aDay, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) AS registedCount, 
        SUM(IF(users.id IS NOT NULL AND user_answer.userid IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS notAnsweredCount
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2015-09-01', INTERVAL units.aCnt + tens.aCnt * 10 DAY) AS aDay
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) units
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 
    ) tens
) date_range
LEFT OUTER JOIN users
ON date_range.aDay = users.registerdate
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_answer
ON users.id = user_answer.userid
GROUP BY date_range.aDay
```

This is getting a range of numbers to add to a date, to give a range of dates (in this case 100 days from 1st September inclusive). This is then LEFT OUTER JOINed against users matching on the register date, and then that is LEFT OUTER JOINed against user_answer. It does a count of distinct user.id to get the number of people who registered on each date, and it sums up where the userids from user_answer is NULL (ie, haven't answered any question).

EDIT - if you do not care about having gaps in the returned data for days where no user registered, and want a list of all days where at least 1 person registered this this simple query will do the job:-

```
SELECT users.registerdate, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) AS registedCount, 
        SUM(IF(user_answer.userid IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS notAnsweredCount
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_answer
ON users.id = user_answer.userid
GROUP BY users.registerdate
```

Comment: Thank you. I have checked the both queries which you given. Both queries are not returning the correct values. Its returning only 0 or 1.

Comment: Can you post some test data in your question so we can test it please?

Comment: Quick test on SQL fiddle and the 2nd seems to work, while I have done a minor change so the 1st one works - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0486d0/3

Comment: Ya its working fine fiddle, I will check it tomorrow and let you know. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following query, it should get you the desired results

```
SELECT results.date, 
    SUM(results.answered) as answered,
    COUNT(results.userid)-SUM(results.answered) as notanswered
FROM
(SELECT @id:= u.id as userid, @regdate:= u.regdate as date,
   (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_answer WHERE updated_date = @regdate AND userid = @id)
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS answered
FROM users u) AS results
GROUP BY results.date
```

Comment: Thank you. I look at your answer but i am not able to understand clearly. Can you please explain little bit?

Comment: The inner selects iterates the answers for all existing users. It assigns the value 1 for all users that answered (i.e. those that have a record in user_answer table for the same date) and the value 0 for all those who didn't. The oute select then parses these results and simply counts how many 1's there are. Does this provide the results you want?

Comment: No, Query takes very long time to execute. Is it because of large data? I have large amount of data in both tables. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The query iterates the data multiple times, so if you have large data it will take some time (for each row of users table a query is performed on user_answer table).

Comment: okay fine i will check it and let you know asap. Thank you so much.